# xpath method of Selenium does not work for Google chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I don't have a lot of experience with Selenium but I am trying to run a code which search for an element in HTML with chromedriver. I keep getting an error as below. The first thing I would like to confirm is that this error cannot be due to the connection with Chromedriver to the web but is because of the way the python script search in the HTML code. Any help would be appreciated.

The error:

```
('no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(text(),\'Find exited companies announced\')]/../.."}\n  (Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.101)', None, None)
```

The code source:

```
<div id="logon-brownContent" style="width:100%;display:true;;padding-bottom: 0px;" class="hideforprinting">
<table width="" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="">
</table>
</div>
</div>
</td></tr></table>
</div>
</td>
<td class="homepage_mainbody-headlines">
<table class="framework_standard">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" valign="top">
        <form action="exitbroker.asp?" method="post" name="oz" id="oz" sumbit="javascript:return validate();">
            <input type="hidden" name="verb" value="8" />
            <input type="hidden" name="dateformat" value="dd/mm/yyyy" />
            <input type="hidden" name="contextid" value="1032390856" />
            <input type="hidden" name="statecodelength" value="0" />
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="framework_page-title">
                                    <span class="framework_page-title">PE Exit Companies: Search</span><br/>                            
                                </td>
                            </tr>   
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="1"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" height="13" width="1"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>            
            <table class="criteriaborder"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%" border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100%;">
                                <tbody>             
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="top">
                                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                                                     <tr>
                                                        <td align="center" valign="middle" width="100%" height="18" class="criteriaheader2">Exits</td>
                                                    </tr>   
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                        <td class="criteriasectionheader"><br />Exit Types</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr valign="top"><td width="200"><input  type="checkbox" name="exitdealtype" value="ipo"/>Initial Public Offering</td><td width="200"><input  type="checkbox" name="exitdealtype" value="sbo"/>Secondary Buyout</td><td width="200"><input  type="checkbox" name="exitdealtype" value="tradesale"/>Trade Sale</td></tr>
</table>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>       
                                    
                                     <tr>
                                        <td class="criteriasectionheader"><br />Date Range</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Find exited companies announced<br><br>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>           
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                        
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>From &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td><input type="text"  name="datefrom" style="width:100" value=""></td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; To &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td><input type="text"  name="dateto" style="width:100" value=""></td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:removeMe(document.oz.datefrom);removeMe(document.oz.dateto);">Clear Date</a></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td><span class="hint">(dd/mm/yyyy)</span></td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td><span class="hint">(dd/mm/yyyy)</span></td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <br />
                                            Please Note: The default start date for our searches has been changed to 01/01/2005. You can still access all 
                                            <br />
                                            of our historical data by inserting the desired start date above. For help or further information please contact 
                                            <br />
                                            your Customer Relationship Consultant.
                                            <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="criteriasectionheader"><br />Industry</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Find exited companies in these sectors.
                                            <br />The industries defined here are affiliated with both the core business and divisions of the portfolio/exited companies.
                                            <br />Multiple select using ctrl and click. The default is set to all.<br><br>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><span class="criterialabel">Sectors<a href="javascript:displaySectorGlossary('../includes/glossary');"><img src="/includes/images/mm-info-icon.gif"></a></span></td>
                                                    <td><span class="criterialabel">Sub-Sectors</span></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><select multiple="multiple" size="6" name="sectorcode" style="width:250px" onChange="javascript:emptyListBox(document.oz.subsectorcode);fillSelect(document.oz.subsectorcode,null,buildSelectedItems(document.oz.sectorcode));"></select> </td>
                                                    <td><select multiple="multiple" size="6" name="subsectorcode" style="width:250px"></select> </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><a name="selectAllSubsectorLink" href="javascript:fillSelect(document.oz.subsectorcode,null,buildSelectedItems(document.oz.sectorcode));selectAll(document.oz.sectorcode);fillSelect(document.oz.subsectorcode,null,buildSelectedItems(document.oz.sectorcode));">Select All Sectors</a> </td>
                                                    <td><a href="javascript:if(!document.oz.domsectoronly.checked){selectAll(document.oz.subsectorcode)};">Select All Sub-Sectors</a> </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><a href="javascript:emptyListBox(document.oz.subsectorcode);deselectAll(document.oz.sectorcode);">Clear All</a><br><br></td>                                
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="4">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="normalsectorsearch" value="" />
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="normalsubsectorsearch" value="" />
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="domsectoronly" value="true"  onclick="javascript:deselectAll(document.oz.subsectorcode);setItemDisableStatus(document.oz.subsectorcode);setItemDisableStatus(document.oz.selectAllSubsectorLink);">Search by dominant sector only<a href="javascript:displayPEPortfolioDominantSectorCountryGlossary('../includes/glossary');"><img src="/includes/images/mm-info-icon.gif" title="More information" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>    
                                    <!--
                                        <td><select size="6" multiple="multiple" name="sectorcode" style="width:250px" ></select> </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                            <a href="javascript:selectAll(document.oz.sectorcode);">Select All</a> 
                                            <a href="javascript:deselectAll(document.oz.sectorcode);">Clear All</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        -->
                                    </tr>    
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="TEXT-ALIGN: right;" class="search_buttons_right">
                                            <input type="button" value="Save Search" class="framework_flatbutton" onclick="javascript:if (validatePage(document.oz)) {document.oz.verb.value=1;document.oz.target='_self';document.oz.submit();};"/>            
                                            <!-- a onmouseover="style.cursor = 'hand'" onclick="javascript:if (validatePage(document.oz)) {document.oz.verb.value=28;defaultDatesWithLocale( document.oz.datefrom, document.oz.dateto, 'dd/mm/yyyy' );if (verifyDateSubSectors(document.oz.datefrom.value)) {countWindow();document.oz.target='_self';document.oz.submit();}}"><img src="/images/button_countresults.gif" border="0" /></a -->
                                            <input type="button" value="Count Results" class="framework_flatbutton" onclick="javascript:submitCount();" />
                                                            
                                            <!-- a onmouseover="style.cursor = 'hand'" onclick="javascript:if (validatePage(document.oz)) {document.oz.verb.value=8;defaultDatesWithLocale( document.oz.datefrom,document.oz.dateto, 'dd/mm/yyyy' );document.oz.target='_self';if (verifyDateSubSectors(document.oz.datefrom.value)) {document.oz.target='_self';document.oz.submit();}};"><img src="/images/button_search.gif" border="0" /></a -->
                                            <input type="button" value="Search" class="framework_flatbutton" onclick="javascript:if (validatePage(document.oz)) {
                                                                                                             document.oz.verb.value=8
                                                                                                            ;document.oz.target='_self'
                                                                                                             defaultDatesWithLocale( document.oz.datefrom,document.oz.dateto, 'dd/mm/yyyy' );
                                                                                                            ; document.oz.target='_self';
                                                                                                            document.oz.submit();
                                                                                                            }" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </tr>
                    </td>
                </tbody>
            </table>    
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="criteriaborder"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%" border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100%;">
                                <tbody>                     
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="top">
                                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                                                     <tr>
                                                        <td align="center" valign="middle" width="100%" height="18" class="criteriaheader2">Further Search Criteria</td>
                                                    </tr>   
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="criteriasectionheader"><br/>Geography</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Find exited companies in these locations.
                                        <br />Multiple select using ctrl and click. The default is set to all. </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td><img src="/images/spacer.gif" width="10" height="1" alt="" /></td><td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><select multiple="multiple" size="6" name="areacode" style="width:200px" onChange="javascript:emptyListBox(document.oz.regioncode);emptyListBox(document.oz.countrycode);fillSelect(document.oz.regioncode,null,buildSelectedItems(document.oz.areacode));emptyListBox(document.oz.statecode);"></select></td>
                                                    <td><select multiple="multiple" size="6" name="regioncode" style="width:200px" onChange="javascript:emptyListBox(document.oz.countrycode);fillSelect(document.oz.countrycode,null,buildSelectedItems(document.oz.regioncode));emptyListBox(document.oz.statecode);"></select></td>
                                                    <td><select multiple="multiple" size="6" name="countrycode" style="width:200px" onChange="javascript:emptyListBox(document.oz.statecode);fillSelect(document.oz.statecode,null,buildSelectedItems(document.oz.countrycode));"></select></td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td><td><select multiple="multiple" size="6" name="statecode" style="width:200px"></select></td>                                                 
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><a href="javascript:emptyListBox(document.oz.regioncode);emptyListBox(document.oz.countrycode);selectAll(document.oz.areacode);fillSelect(document.oz.regioncode,null,buildSelectedItems(document.oz.areacode));">Select All</a></td>
                                                    <td><a href="javascript:emptyListBox(document.oz.countrycode);selectAll(document.oz.regioncode);fillSelect(document.oz.countrycode,null,buildSelectedItems(document.oz.regioncode));">Select All</a></td>
                                                    <td><a href="javascript:selectAll(document.oz.countrycode);emptyListBox(document.oz.statecode);fillSelect(document.oz.statecode,null,buildSelectedItems(document.oz.countrycode));">Select All</a></td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td><td><a href="javascript:selectAll(document.oz.statecode);">Select All</a></td>
                                                </tr>                                               
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><a href="javascript:emptyListBox(document.oz.regioncode);emptyListBox(document.oz.countrycode);emptyListBox(document.oz.statecode);deselectAll(document.oz.areacode);">Clear All</a></td>                                               
                                                </tr>                                                                                                                                                   
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                        <td class="criteriasectionheader"><br/>PE House</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Find exit companies who are currently held by specific PE Houses.
                                        <br />Maximum of 50 selections allowed.</td >
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a class="search_lookup" href="javascript:openWin('qpehousenotapproved','hyperlink','pehousesysid','select-multiple','pehousesysiddescription','');">Lookup</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select size="4" multiple="multiple" name="pehousesysid" style="width:350px"></select>                          
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="pehousesysiddescription"  />
                                                    </td>   
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a href="javascript:removeLookupOption(document.oz.pehousesysid);removeMe(document.oz.pehousesysid);">Remove</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="criteriasectionheader"><br/>Advisors</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Find exited companies who have been advised by these companies.
                                            <br />Maximum of 50 selections allowed.
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a class="search_lookup" href="javascript:openWin('ecadvisor','hyperlink','advisorcompanysysid','select-multiple','advisorcompanysysiddescription','');">Lookup</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select size="4" multiple="multiple" name="advisorcompanysysid" style="width:350px"></select>
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="advisorcompanysysiddescription" />
                                                    </td>                                               
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a href="javascript:removeLookupOption(document.oz.advisorcompanysysid);removeMe(document.oz.advisorcompanysysid);">Remove</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><br /><span class="criteriasectionheader">Deal Value</span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Find exited companies with the following deal value. </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><p><span class="criterialabel">Currency</span></p></td> 
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td><select id="currencycode" name="currencycode"><option value="AUD">AUD</option>
<option value="CHF">CHF</option>
<option value="CNY">CNY</option>
<option value="EUR">EUR</option>
<option value="GBP">GBP</option>
<option value="HKD">HKD</option>
<option value="INR">INR</option>
<option value="JPY">JPY</option>
<option value="USD" selected="">USD</option></select></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="180"><p><span class="criterialabel">Minimum value in millions</span></p></td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td> 
                                                    <td><p><input type="text" name="mindealvalue" size="12" value="" onkeypress="checkMinimumValue();" onkeyup="checkMinimumValue();" /></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="180"><span class="criterialabel">Maximum value in millions</span></td>   
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" name="maxdealvalue" size="12" value=""></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>       
                                    <tr><td><br>Include deals with undisclosed value <input type="checkbox" name="undiscloseddealvalues" value="true" Checked></td></tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="criteriasectionheader"><br/>Exited Companies</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Maximum of 50 selections allowed.</td >
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a class="search_lookup" href="javascript:openWin('eccompany','hyperlink','eccompanysysid','select-multiple','eccompanysysiddescription','');">Lookup</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select size="4" multiple="multiple" name="eccompanysysid" style="width:350px"></select>
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="eccompanysysiddescription"  />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a href="javascript:removeLookupOption(document.oz.eccompanysysid);removeMe(document.oz.eccompanysysid);">Remove</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="criteriasectionheader"><br/>Free Text Search</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Please use the Free Text Search by typing in a keyword or phrase to identify the required portfolio.
                                            <br />
                                            <span class="hint">Searches on companies' information, deal description, and condition, type, nature, consideration structure.<br><br></span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="150" class="criterialabel">Search</td>
                                                    <td><input type="text" name="textsearch" style="width:250px" value="" /></td>
                                                    <td><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr valign="top"><td width="350"><input checked type="radio" name="andorfreetext" value="and"/>Match all words<br><input  type="radio" name="andorfreetext" value="or"/>Match any word<br><input  type="radio" name="andorfreetext" value="phrase"/>Match exact phrase</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                    
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>               
                                    
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="TEXT-ALIGN: right;" class="search_buttons_right">
                                            <input type="button" value="Save Search" class="framework_flatbutton" onclick="javascript:if (validatePage(document.oz)) {document.oz.verb.value=1;document.oz.target='_self';document.oz.submit();};"/>            
                                            <!-- a onmouseover="style.cursor = 'hand'" onclick="javascript:if (validatePage(document.oz)) {document.oz.verb.value=28;defaultDatesWithLocale( document.oz.datefrom, document.oz.dateto, 'dd/mm/yyyy' );if (verifyDateSubSectors(document.oz.datefrom.value)) {countWindow();document.oz.target='_self';document.oz.submit();}}"><img src="/images/button_countresults.gif" border="0" /></a -->
                                            <input type="button" value="Count Results" class="framework_flatbutton" onclick="javascript:submitCount();" />
                                                            
                                            <!-- a onmouseover="style.cursor = 'hand'" onclick="javascript:if (validatePage(document.oz)) {document.oz.verb.value=8;defaultDatesWithLocale( document.oz.datefrom,document.oz.dateto, 'dd/mm/yyyy' );document.oz.target='_self';if (verifyDateSubSectors(document.oz.datefrom.value)) {document.oz.target='_self';document.oz.submit();}};"><img src="/images/button_search.gif" border="0" /></a -->
                                            <input type="button" value="Search" class="framework_flatbutton" onclick="javascript:if (validatePage(document.oz)) {
                                                                                                             document.oz.verb.value=8
                                                                                                            ;document.oz.target='_self'; 
                                                                                                             defaultDatesWithLocale( document.oz.datefrom,document.oz.dateto, 'dd/mm/yyyy' );
                                                                                                            document.oz.target='_self';
                                                                                                            document.oz.submit();
                                                                                                            }" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </tr>
                    </td>
                </tbody>            
            </table>        
       </form>      
       
       <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        <!--


        function validatePage(objitem) {
            
            selectAll(objitem.pehousesysid);
            selectAll(objitem.eccompanysysid);

            objitem.eccompanysysid.required=false;
            objitem.eccompanysysid.description='Portfolio Company Name';
            objitem.eccompanysysid.datatype='alphanumeric';

            selectAll(objitem.advisorcompanysysid);

            objitem.advisorcompanysysid.required=false;
            objitem.advisorcompanysysid.description='Advisor Name';
            objitem.advisorcompanysysid.datatype='alphanumeric';    
                
            // locale info.
            objitem.localedateformat='dd/mm/yyyy';
            objitem.localecurrencycode='USD';
            objitem.localelanguagecode='en_eu';
            objitem.localetimezone='235';
            
            
            objitem.mindealvalue.required=false;
            objitem.mindealvalue.description='Currency minimum value in millions';
            objitem.mindealvalue.datatype='decimal';
            objitem.mindealvalue.min =0;
            objitem.mindealvalue.max=1000000000000000000;
            objitem.maxdealvalue.required=false;
            objitem.maxdealvalue.description='Currency maximum value in millions';
            objitem.maxdealvalue.datatype='decimal';
            objitem.maxdealvalue.min=0;
            objitem.maxdealvalue.max=1000000000000000000;
            objitem.datefrom.required=false;
            objitem.datefrom.description='Date from';
            objitem.datefrom.datatype='date';
            objitem.dateto.required=false;
            objitem.dateto.description='Date to';
            objitem.dateto.datatype='date';
        
            if (objitem.statecode)
            {
                objitem.statecodelength.value = objitem.statecode.length;
            }       
                    
            // DanielC: 7/11/08: Case 107136: set the hidden field so that it will end up in the token XML and can be used in criteria.xml
            if (document.oz.domsectoronly.checked == false)
            {
                document.oz.normalsectorsearch.value = "true";
                document.oz.normalsubsectorsearch.value = "true";
            }
                    
            return verify(objitem,false);
        }
       
       
        function submitCount()
        {
            if (validatePage(document.oz)) {
                var dOz = document.oz;
                //need to change pPopup variable to pPopup=1 to ensure no chrome on popup in event of failure
                var vAction = dOz.action;
                dOz.action = (dOz.action.search(/pPopup/) == -1) ? dOz.action+= "&pPopup=1" : dOz.action.replace(/pPopup=./,"pPopup=1");    
                defaultDatesWithLocale( document.oz.datefrom,document.oz.dateto, 'dd/mm/yyyy' );
                dOz.verb.value=28;
                countWindow();
                document.oz.submit();
                dOz.action = vAction;
            }
        } 
        
      //-->
    </script>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td class="homepage_mainbody-leaguetbl"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100%"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div><footer class="acuris-footer" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas
```

A piece of code with xpath not sending error:

```
def openSearchPageCommon(self,url,clear_xpath) :
    self.drv.get(url)
    for x in self.drv.find_elements_by_xpath(clear_xpath) :
        x.click()
        
def openSearchPage(self) :
    xpath = "//form[@action='portfoliobroker.asp?']//table//*[contains(text(),'Clear Date')]"
    self.openSearchPageCommon(self.tgt,xpath)
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mmmm_lib.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.drv.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Find exited companies announced')]/../..")
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(text(),'Find exited companies announced')]/../.."}
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML source?

Comment: Can you share the relevant html ?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am not sure I am allowed to share this. There is my name in the HTML as It needs login with restricted data. does it help if I only share part of the HTML where the key word I look for are written?

Comment: @delalma You can edit the HTML attribute value where your name is displayed and put some dummy value in place and provide us with the relevant HTML

Comment: You can print page resource as well, we can take a look. also use @ to reply, otherwise we don't the notification

Comment: @cruisepandey thanks, I have put the larger part of the code but Stack does not support more so I removed part of it. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

May be its because the element you are trying to locate is in an `iframe` or in a `shadow dom`. And also make sure that the `xpath` points only one element in the Dom.

If its in an `iframe` you need switch to that frame and then try to locate the element.

if its in a `shadow root`, `open` you need to get the shadow-root first to locate the required element.

Comment: does not seem to have iframe in there

Comment: What about a `shadow root`?

Comment: I could not find any "shadow" by Ctrl+F

Comment: Then check the xpath, it is pointing to single element or many others.

Comment: Examine the Dom carefully.

Comment: it is pointing to a single element. I am running all this into a Docker container. Could it be the reason any way?

Comment: I dont see any "\" in the "Find ... announced". Check if this xpath works - `//td[text()='Find exited companies announced']`. If not, does the element appear when you click on any other option, since its in a table.

Comment: the error has changed with your xpath `("invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression ///td[text()='Find exited companies announced'] because of the following error:\nSyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '///td[text()='Find exited companies announced']' is not a valid XPath expression.\n  (Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.101)", None, None)`

Comment: I don't see a table on the website but there is to box to fill under "Find exited companies announced". I have also added a piece of code which worked.

Comment: I also tried with another element in the page but I got the same error `('no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(text(),\'Clear Date\')]/../.."}\n  (Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.101)', None, None)`. I believe that is not due to the syntax but I am not sure what is the cause.

Comment: I have no more suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should try with css selector written below :-

```
table.criteriaborder:nth-of-type(2) tr:nth-of-type(5) td
```

since the xpath that you are using, depends on a text which is basically a **text node**

if it's python that you are working on, you could try the below code :

```
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table.criteriaborder:nth-of-type(2) tr:nth-of-type(5) td").text)
```